# adding libxml library to project in Anjutha

Tags: gtk, libxml2, anjuta

How can i add libxml library in a project created with Anjutha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to "Project properties", go to the "Packages" tab, click on the module you want to add it to (there is probably only one), click "Add package", and look for "libxml-2.0" in the list. If it's not there, you probably need to install some libxml2-devel package for your distribution.